# Mysql get total of matched items from two tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables as given below...

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_project_skills` (`id`, `projectId`, `skillId`) VALUES
(17, 2, 44),
(27, 2, 43),
(31, 2, 78),
(33, 142, 79),
(35, 123, 88);


INSERT INTO `tbl_user_skills` (`id`, `userId`, `skillId`) VALUES
(2, 1, 44),
(3, 1, 78),
(5, 23, 45),
(6, 1, 36),
(7, 23, 88);
```

I want to find that how many skills are matched of user with each project like below

```
-----------------------------------------------------
userId  |  projectId  | number_of_matched_skills
-----------------------------------------------------
1       |   2         |  2
1       |   142       |  0
1       |   123       |  0
23      |   2         |  0
23      |   142       |  0
23      |   123       |  1
------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried below solution for the same...

```
SELECT ps.projectId, us.userId, ps.skillId AS pskillid, us.skillId AS uskillid, @points_veri:= (CASE WHEN '44' IN(ps.skillId) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN '43' IN(ps.skillId) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + (CASE WHEN '78' IN(ps.skillId) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS number_of_matched_skills FROM tbl_user_skills AS us, tbl_project_skills AS ps
```

But I can't get it right. Hope you guys can give a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have another table for store user and project, or this query will need get `userId` from `tbl_user_skills` and `projectId` from `tbl_project_skills` first, then do cross join, then join `tbl_user_skills` and `tbl_project_skills` to do aggregation:

```
select
    main.userId,
    main.projectId,
    count(ps.projectId) as number_of_matched_skills
from (
    select u.userId, p.projectId 
    from (
        select distinct projectId from tbl_project_skills
    ) p
    cross join (
        select distinct userId from tbl_user_skills
    ) u
) main
left join tbl_user_skills us on us.userId = main.userId
left join tbl_project_skills ps on ps.skillId = us.skillId and main.projectId = ps.projectId
group by main.userId, main.projectId
```

Here is a [**demo**](http://rextester.com/PDTNL83329) in [rextester.com](http://rextester.com).

Comment: Yes actually I do have separate tables for projects and users So i will get those two entities as you suggested and thanks man for all you help and time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option without having another table. Make an `OUTER JOIN` and then a `GROUP BY` on skillId.

```
SELECT userid, 
       projectid, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN p.skillId>1 AND u.skillId>1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS skills 
FROM tbl_user_skills u
FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_project_skills p
ON u.skillId = p.skillId
GROUP BY userid, projectid
ORDER BY skills DESC
```